# How to remove CustomView from UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uikit, uibutton

I'm wanting to remove a image from a uibarbuttonitem and take it back to the default button style. The code I'm using to set the customview for the baritem is:

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 79, 29.0);
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagehere.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.myItem initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

So what I'm asking is how can I remove the backButton CustomView and take it back to my default style? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `[self.myItem initWithCustomView:backButton]` is wrong. You should always be doing something like `self.myItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton]`.

It does not seem that you can change the type of the UIBarButtonItem; when I tried assigning nil to the `customView` property in a test app just now it screwed up the whole toolbar. Your best bet would be to just create a new UIBarButtonItem and reset the toolbars `items` array.

Comment: Isn't self.myItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] leaking memory?

Comment: @hennes: Good point, +1 for you. `[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease]` then.

Comment: I think it also depends on the @property declaration of myItem.

Comment: +1, I encounter the same problem, and I will try to reassign the `items` array for tool bar.

Answer (score -1):

Simply remove it by

```
self.myItem =  nil;
```

Comment: When I did this the custom view disappeared but the default button style didn't reappear, so I was left with an invisible button.